# Where do I find the history Stack Exchange data dump on archive?

Tags: support, stack-exchange, data-dump

I am now following a Hadoop course on "MapReduce Design Patterns", which needs to import Stack Overflow's data.

I find the latest dump is here, https://archive.org/details/stackexchange.

And as you know, the download speed is limited in some countries. So I want to find a medium-sized dump. But I can't find the history dumps on the archive.org.

Comment: Maybe helpful: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/224922/158100

Comment: What is a *"history dump"*? Or do you mean *"dump of [History](https://history.stackexchange.com/tour)"*?

Comment: @Peter Mortensen Yes, sorry for my poor english.